# Copy huge amount of table data (1 TB) from SQL Server to Azure blob in fast speed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bigdata, data-migration, azure-blob-storage

I want to copy the table data which has a huge data volume (1 TB) from SQL Server to Azure blob storage.

I have a table `Employee_Activity` with columns

```
Name, EmpName, CreatedDate
```

I want to copy all the data which was created after 2011-01-01 to an Azure blob.

The amount of data is so huge that even for 1 month, the record count is 100 million.

I have created an SSIS job which will select data in batches and puts it in Azure, but it is very slow.

Can anyone help me with the approach to export the data?

Comment: Is the SQL Server on premises?

Comment: Yes the SQL Server is on-premises

Comment: There may be many bottlenecks then. I suggest you first go to the local machine and use `BCP` and export in native mode `-n` to a local drive. That will take a certain amount of time. Then use`AzCopy` to copy that file to blob storage. Whichever is the slowest step is your bottleneck. You may also want to try Azure Data Factory to do this.

Comment: I have tried the BCP export the time bcp takes is higher than my ssis job to copy same amount of data